# Encoding binary to DNA sequencing in java

Tags: java

I would like to encode binary sequence to DNA sequence by following truth table:

```
00 = A
01 = C
10 = G
11 = T
```

For example, `11000110` would result in `TACG`. Can someone help me, please?

Following is my code:

```
String ddna=" ";
     
Dictionary phoneBook = new Hashtable();//creating dictionary in java we can use hashtable

// put() method
phoneBook.put("00", "A");
phoneBook.put("01", "G");
phoneBook.put("10", "C");
phoneBook.put("11", "T");
```

Comment: You haven't what ? Shown your attempts ? This is not a free coding service. Try something, explain what works/doesn't work, then people will help you

Comment: You miss actual question... Try to make some tutorial for loops and than try to do something like: "take two characters. If it is equal to "00", print A. If it is equal to 01, print G... Than take next two characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is fixed you can simply use `if` statements to determine the correct letter like this:

```
public static String convert(String input) {
    if (input.length() % 2 == 1) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 2) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == '0') {
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) == '0') {
                sb.append("A");
            } else {
                sb.append("G");
            }
        } else {
            if (input.charAt(i + 1) == '0') {
                sb.append("C");
            } else {
                sb.append("T");
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: can you plz decode this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is an other field:

```
/**
 * @param length in "letters"
 */
String dna(byte[] data, int length) {
    if (data.length * 4 < length || length < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient data ("
            + (data.length * 4) + " for length " + length);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    int byteI = -1;
    int b;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int j = i % 4;
        if (j == 0) {
            ++byteI;
            b = (int) date[byteI];
        }
        int n = (b >> (6 - 2*j)) & 3;
        sb,append("AGCT".charAt(n));
    } 
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: It isn't working please help me

Comment: I have no java compiler at hand,  Changed ACGT to AGCT